# numeros aleatorios no repetidos java

Tags: java

Hola como coseguririan ustedes que en este codigo no se generasen dos numeros aleatorios iguales. es un array de 6 filas y 10 columnas al que le asigno  numeros aleatorios del 1 al 1000

```
int[][] num = new int[6][10];
for(int f=0;f<=5;f++){
        for(int c=0;c<=9;c++){
            num[f][c]=(int) (Math.random()*1000+1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No puedes evitar que se generen números aleatorios sin repetición. Lo que deberías es comprobar si ya lo has asignado a alguna posición de tu matriz. Cada vez que generes un valor, comprobar que no está en la matriz. Si está, generas uno nuevo, sino lo pones en la posición que le toque y a por el siguiente.

Comment: O bien compruebas que no esté ya en tu array, o de una manera mas sencilla lo que puedes hacer es crear un Arraylist y cada vez que generes un numero aleatorio primero compruebas que no esté en el arraylist, y si no está lo añades tanto en el arraylist como en tu array

Comment: La opción que te ha sugerido @Pikoh es buena y seguramente más fácil de entender y rápida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un array registro de numeros y revisar si el random lanzado esta en el registro, si esta repite la operacion sino registras en tu matriz y prosigues:

```
ArrayList<int> registry = new ArrayList<int>();
int random;
int[][] num = new int[6][10];

for(int f=0;f<=5;f++){
    for(int c=0;c<=9;c++){
        do{
            random = (int) (Math.random()*1000+1);
        }while(!IntStream.of(registry).anyMatch(x -> x == random));
        registry.add(random);
        num[f][c]= random;
    }
}
```